# Start webservice on tomcat error

Tags: web-services, tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to write a webservice with netbeans and when i use tomcat server it can deploy but can not start. the following message is what netbeans says when i try to start the webapp on tomcat in servers tab:
Failed application at context path /webapp could not be started.

this is its log

Jul 22, 2014 9:11:12 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
Jul 22, 2014 9:11:12 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/E:/ETC_PlazaStationSoft/WebApp/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/webservices-rt.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.2 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/guide/standards/)
**************************************WARNING***************************************
To use JAX-WS 2.1 with JDK 6, newer versions of API jars need to be in bootclasspath
before rt.jar. To do this you can use Java endorsed mechanism to override what is in
Java platform. The easiest way to do so is to put JAX-WS 2.1 and JAXB 2.1 API jars to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\endorsed folder.

---

java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/E:/ETC_PlazaStationSoft/WebApp/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/webservices-rt.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.2 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/guide/standards/)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.(ModelBuilder.java:173)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:456)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:154)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:201)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jul 22, 2014 9:11:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 22, 2014 9:11:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/WebApp] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 22, 2014 9:11:12 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here to diagnose the problem - that message simply means something went wrong during the startup process. You'll have to inspect the tomcat log files to find out what the underlying problem was. You'll probably find a number of exception traces in the log, the most helpful one is usually the last level of "caused by" on the earliest exception.